# Thumbnail only show part of image

Tags: html, css, widget

I've created a popular post widget and it appears that the thumbnail is only showing a portion of the actual image, and not the whole thing.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        document.body.className = document.body.className.replace(&#39;loading&#39;, &#39;&#39;);
      }, 10);
  </script>
<script type='text/javascript'>                   
function changeThumbSize(id,size){
var blogGadget = document.getElementById(id);
var replacement = blogGadget.innerHTML;
blogGadget.innerHTML = replacement.replace(/s72-c/g,&quot;s&quot;+size+&quot;-c&quot;);
var thumbnails = blogGadget.getElementsByTagName(&quot;img&quot;);
for(var i=0;i&lt;thumbnails.length;i++){ 
thumbnails[i].width = size; 
thumbnails[i].height = size; 
}
}
changeThumbSize(&quot;PopularPosts1&quot;,300);                   
</script>
```

I've gone through it a million times but can't figure out whats going wrong.

```
<style type='text/css'>
.PopularPosts .item-thumbnail a {
clip: auto;
display: block;
height: 180px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 300px;
margin-left: -10px;
}
.PopularPosts .item-thumbnail img {
position: relative;
top: -30px;
transition:all .2s linear;
 -o-transition:all .5s linear;
-moz-transition:all .2s linear;
-webkit-transition:all .2s linear;
}

.PopularPosts .item-thumbnail img:hover{
opacity:.6;
filter:alpha(opacity=60)
}
.PopularPosts .widget-content ul li {
color: #555555;
}

.PopularPosts .item-title {
clear:both;
font: 11px raleway;
color: #000;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: center;
margin-right: 10px;
}

.PopularPosts .item-title a{
color: #000
  }
.PopularPosts .item-title a:hover{
color: #515151
  }

.PopularPosts .item-snippet {
display: none;
}

.widget .widget-item-control a img {
height: 18px;
width: 18px;

}

</style>
```

Any suggestions?? Thanks :)

Comment: When you call `changeThumbSize` the size passed is 300, but in css `.PopularPosts .item-thumbnail a` you have `height: 180px; overflow: hidden;` so this is an expected behaviour. Change the height from 180 to 300 and you should be fine.

Comment: Hi a fiddle for reference will be a great help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Could you jsfiddle your code?*

I think you can use `background-size: contain;`, it will fit your image inside your thumb area.

Check it out: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover